# How to override or disable toast when copying text in Android 12 programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, toast, android-12

In Android 12 and higher when copying will get toast with message "APP pasted from your clipboard.", but i want replace it with my custom snackbar.

this is how i implement copy :

```kotlin
fun String.copyToClipboard(context: Context, label: String) {
  val clipboard = context.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
  val clip = ClipData.newPlainText(label, this)
  clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)

CustomSnackBar(
 viewBinding.root,
 title = getString(R.string.ticket_number_hasbeen_copied),
 style = TensSnackbarDefaults.GeneralSnackbarStyle()
)
}
```

im expecting to hide/disable toast when copying, but i dont know to hide it, i was reading documentation and google it.

Comment: You can't, that's OS level functionality and done automatically.

Comment: You're getting this when _copying_?  Not when pasting?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicate displays of information, just add this verification:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.S_V2)
    Toast.makeText(context, “Copied”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```